# Locust AWS python requirements fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, python

Folks,
  Trying to setup Locust in AWS using latest amazon linux.  After installing locust, i get the following when starting in master mode:

```
locust -f foo.py --master
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/locust", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2655, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 648, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: requests>=2.4.1
```

What would be the most elegant fix for this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if anyone cares, upgrading python to v 2.7 solves my problem:

http://www.lecloud.net/post/61401763496/install-update-to-python-2-7-and-latest-pip-on-ec2

```
33  yum install make automake gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel git-core -y
34  yum install python27-devel -y
35  rm /usr/bin/python
36  ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
37  cp /usr/bin/yum /usr/bin/_yum_before_27
38  sed -i s/python/python2.6/g /usr/bin/yum
39  sed -i s/python2.6/python2.6/g /usr/bin/yum
40  python -V
```